# How can I rename a Google Calendar event without opening an edit window?

Tags: google-calendar

It was previously possible without leaving the main view - by clicking the event and editing the title in place.

With the new Material design I can't seem to do the same. I can only click the pencil icon and open another window.

Can it be that Google removed such a powerful feature? I'm using calendar to plan my week (obviously) and I need to shuffle and move existing events a lot. It will triple the time for me doing so. Really frustrating.

Perhaps there's a setting somewhere? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no setting you've missed. This seems to be a bit of functionality they removed from the new calendar.

(Right-clicking on an event in the calendar view will give you the option to delete or change the color, but that's all.)

If this is important to you, you can let Google know by using the "Send feedback" tool found in the main menu.